# Using java to export csv files from SQL SERVER table

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

As the title states, I am using java to export csv files from remote SQL SERVER table.
I know that I can do this by using the bcp command. I am looking for way to do this without calling the bcp command directly.

For example, we can use bcp to do a bulk upload. But we can also use the 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy class to do the same thing. This way I don't have to install bcp.

Is there a similar class or library that allows exporting data from a remote SQL Server to csv without using the bcp command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to find a tool or a library to do the export for me. As far as I can tell, there aren't any.
I ended up installing the bcp utility tool and calling it from java as external process using the [ZT Process Executor](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec).